# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' using Python3 on Hackerrank

Tags: python-3.x

```
lists=[]
sum=0
n,k=input().split()
j=int(n)
g=int(k)
for i in range(0,j):
    m=int(input())
    lists.append(m)
b=int(input())
for items in lists:
    sum=sum+items
actsum=(sum-lists[g])/2
if(actsum==b):
    print('Bon Appetit')
else:
    l=sum/2-actsum
    print(l)
```

I'm getting this error when trying to compile a piece of code on Hackerrank but it gets compiled and works perfect when running it on PyCharm .

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 7, in <module>
    m=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 10 2 9'   ---->This is the error that I get .

Comment: Use `edit` to add all important information into the question itself. You might also want to add a paragraph on what this program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

This program assumes that the price for each item on the bill will be supplied on its own separate line.  The program expects to consume one of those items on each pass through this loop:

```
for i in range(0,j):
    m=int(input())
    lists.append(m)
```

However, the [problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bon-appetit/problem) says:

> The second line contains *n* space-separated integers *bill[n]* where *0 <= n < i*.

So in fact the item prices don't come on separate lines.  They all come on a single line.  The program blows up here when it tries to convert that entire line to an integer:

```py
    m=int(input())
```

The line "3 10 2 9" returned by `input()` is not a valid integer, so the `int` function throws an exception that kills the program.

To fix, use an approach similar to the way you treated the first line.  Take the line from `input()`, then `split()` the line into separate pieces, then convert each piece into an `int` and append that `int` to your `lists` list.